# batch files command line arguments

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, command-line-arguments

hi i am setting a string in a variable

set main=svn commit -m "Build version number update" install\msbuild\VersionNumber.txt

and passing "%main%" as a command line argument  to another script template.bat .

but in template.bat "Build version number update" is cosidered a 2nd arg and rest as 3rd

one.

please tell me how to pass the variable main as a single argument.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the 2nd bat file;

```
@echo whole command line is %*
```

Comment: Nice one, didn't thought about %*. It won't work however, if more arguments are passed to template.bat.

Answer (score 1):

Variable %main% contains spaces, so if you use it like this:

```
template.bat %main%
```

Batch will interpret it like this:

```
template.bat svn blah blah blah
```

So %1 will be only "svn", etc. If you want entire contents of %main% to be treated as a single argument, you have to put quotes around it:

```
template.bat "%main%"
```

The problem is, the %1 now contains those quotes. You have to remove them inside template.bat using tilde:

```
%~1
```